# Recursive function does not fully recurse object / sub-objects

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a recursive function `find()` that tries to find a item with an given ID. Below I extracted the relevant parts from the class to make an example to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Item {
private:
    std::vector<Item> subitems;

public:
    std::wstring id;

public:
    Item()
    : subitems(0), id(L"") {}

    Item(const Item& rhs)
    : subitems(rhs.subitems.size()) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs.subitems.size(); ++i)
            subitems[i] = rhs.subitems[i];
        id = rhs.id;
    }

    Item& operator==(const Item& rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs.subitems.size(); ++i)
                subitems[i] = rhs.subitems[i];
            id = rhs.id;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<Item> getSubitems() {
        return subitems;
    }

    Item addSubitems(Item * item ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, item);
        for (Item * arg = item; arg != NULL; arg = va_arg(args, Item *)) {
            subitems.push_back(*item);
        }
        va_end(args);

        return *this;
    }

    Item addSubitems(std::vector<Item>& items) {
        for (typename std::vector<Item>::value_type &item : items) {
            subitems.push_back(item);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    static Item * find(int id, std::vector<Item>& items) {
        std::wstring id_str = std::to_wstring(id);
        std::wcout << "--> find id=" << id_str << std::endl;
        std::wcout << "size of items=" << items.size() << std::endl;
        for (typename std::vector<Item>::value_type &c : items) {
            std::wcout << "it .. cur id=" << c.id << std::endl;
            if (!c.id.empty() && c.id == id_str) {
                std::wcout << "==> found" << std::endl;
                return &c;
            }

            if (!(c.getSubitems()).empty()) {
                std::wcout << "-> find " << id << " in subitems" << std::endl;
                std::vector<Item> subcls = c.getSubitems();
                std::wcout << "size of subitems=" << subcls.size() << std::endl;
                Item * sub = find(id, subcls);
                if (sub != NULL) {
                    std::wcout << "==> found in subitems" << std::endl;
                    return sub;
                }
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};

int main() {
    Item c1;
    c1.id = L"0";
    Item c2;
    c2.id = L"1";
    Item c3;
    c3.id = L"2";
    Item c4;
    c4.id = L"3";
    //std::vector<Item> cll4({c4});
    //std::vector<Item> cll3({c3});
    //std::vector<Item> cll2({c2});

    c3.addSubitems(&c4, NULL);
    c2.addSubitems(&c3, NULL);
    c1.addSubitems(&c2, NULL);

    //c1.addSubitems(cll2);
    //c2.addSubitems(cll3);
    //c3.addSubitems(cll4);

    std::vector<Item> items({c1});

    Item * c = Item::find(2, items);
    std::wcout 
        << "Found item=" 
        << ((c != NULL && c == &c3) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    std::wcout
        << ((c != NULL) ? c->id : L"") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I create a few `Items` and add `sub-Items` to them. Now I want to be able to lookup an ID of an item and return the found item or sub-item object by using the recursive `find()` method. 
If I add items with the `addSubitems()` (with variable args), it will find the item but doesn't return a (valid) item object. If I use the addSubitems method by passing a vector of items the find() method does not recurse fully all subitems.

Actually I am sitting on this problem now the last 4 hours and I am out of ideas, it might be a simple thing I oversee or miss. I added the copy constructor / and assignment operator afterwords (just to see if there are changes in behaviour), but no. Do not worry about the item ID being a string type (the reason is for later serialization), this class is in its early stages so I for now I chose a string type.

Could somebody please point me the flaws/problems to get this class straight! Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one problem with the "it will find the item but doesn't return a (valid) item object." is:

You send Item* to the addSubItems method and then you add a (*Item) to the vector;
This will initialize a copy c'tor, so later on, when you do is &c == &c3, obviously it would be false, since while the objects are INDEED identical, the addresses would not be since they are copies of one another.

Not that I understand why you would want to copy but the solution would be to either test

```
if (c == c3) -> activating the Item operator ==
```

OR allocate the members, save a

```
std::vector<Item*> subitems;
```

and then ask `if (c == c3) -> asking about the addresses`

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, indeed, after reading your answer it sounds clear to me. For now I use option number 2 (vector of pointers), even if I am not very happy with it, but while developing I might change a few things.

Comment: make sure you allocate them